# Relay Modern refetch does not pass new data

Tags: reactjs, graphql, relay, relaymodern

I am quite new to Relay Modern so I may be doing something wrong here. Also I'm having a hard time finding documentation on how this should be done.

I have an app which presents a virtual directory structure view built in React with the following structure:

```html
<ProjectDrive>
  <QueryRenderer>
     <ProjectDriveContainer>
        <ProjectDriveComponent>
```

When the view loads the GraphQL query specified in the `QueryRenderer` is executed and the data is passed to the `ProjectDriveContainer` component and it renders correctly. This component is created like so:

```js
const ProjectDriveContainer = createRefetchContainer(ProjectDriveComponent, {
        processMeta: TrackingBoardFragment.processMeta,
        directory: ProjectDriveComponentFragment.directory
}, ProjectDriveComponentRefetchQuery);
```

A method for changing the directory performs a refetch with different variables and I can see this query executing and returning the correct data in the browser's network tab. The `componentWillReceiveProps` method receives the new props but these are the old original props - i.e. the new data has not replaced the object in the props.

My queries look like this:

Original query

```
query DriveDataQuery($processId: Int!, $boardClass: String!, $boardType: String!, $filters: JSONString, $directoryType: DirectoryType!, $root: Boolean!, $directoryId: ID) {
  processMeta(processId: $processId, boardClass: $boardClass, boardType: $boardType, filters: $filters) {
    ...TrackingBoardComponent_processMeta
  }
  userProcessOptions(processId: $processId) {
    ...NavbarComponent_userProcessOptions
  }
  directory(processId: $processId, directoryType: $directoryType, root: $root, directoryId: $directoryId) {
    ...ProjectDriveComponent_directory
  }
}
```

Refetch query:

```
query ProjectDriveComponentRefetchQuery($processId: Int, $directoryId: ID!, $directoryType: DirectoryType!, $root: Boolean!) {
    directory(processId: $processId, directoryType: $directoryType, root: $root, directoryId: $directoryId) {
        ...ProjectDriveComponent_directory
    }
}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Have you solved this problem yet? I've exactly the same issue.

Comment: No, I haven't solved this yet. Surely this must be happening to more people....

Comment: have the exact same problem, @JaroslavZavodny did you manage to solve it ?

Comment: @MehdiJorJor Yeah, I solved this. Check the answer below. Hope it will help!

Comment: @JaroslavZavodny Aww too bad that isn't my case, thanks!